# How to remove child objects from a @ManyToMany relation with lots of children in JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, many-to-many

Let's say I have two entities: Organization and User. Every user can be a member of many organizations and every organization can have many users.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @ManyToMany
    Set<Organization> organizations;
    //...
}

@Entity
public class Organization {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="organizations")
    Set<User> users;
    //...
}
```

Now, I want to remove an organization (let's say it has 1000 members).
When the user has few organizations, this code is ok:

```
void removeOrgFromUser(Integer userId,Integer orgId){
    User user = session.load(User.class, userId);
    for (Organization org : user.organizations) {
        if(org.getId().equals(orgId))
            user.organizations.remove(org);
    }
    session.update(user);
}
```

But when organization count is 10,000, this solution does not have good performance.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Remove rows from join table.

Comment: I want do that with hibernate or hql ,

Comment: @Antoniossss with sql native?

Comment: Yes, use prepared statement with criteria of user_id and departament_id

Comment: Try JBNizet's answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699153/on-delete-cascade-hibernate-manytomany
Clear the collection of users from the organization before deleting the organization.
Another way is through SQL as @Antoniossss suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have more than 50 or 100 child entities, you shouldn't map a collection.

Therefore, `@OneToMany` is misleading because, in reality, `@OneToFew` makes more sense. So, when many means 1000 or 10000, mapping such a collection becomes a real performance problem.

In this case, just break the [`@ManyToMany`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) association so that you map the join table `UserOrganization`.

In this case, you just need the 2 `@ManyToOne` associations on the join table, and, you can just issue a bulk delete query like this:

```
delete from UserOrganization uo
where uo.organization = :organization
```

That's it!